# Creating paths with variables (move a folder and contents to new folder)

Tags: c#, winforms

looked all over and found plenty of stuff regarding this but none are using variables to form paths. What I need to do is move a folder, sub-folders and files to a new path on button click. So far none of what I found worked. At the moment, i'm getting no files or folders moved what so ever. The current solution I tried is from MSDN and tried to adapt it to my code. If you could correct the code and show me an example it would be great. I don't know what i'm doing wrong here. Here is the code:

```
private void CopyPartsToProject()
    {
        string sourcePath = (pathToQuotes + "/" + client_name.Text + "/" + quote_id.Text);
        string targetPath = (pathToClient + "/" + client_name.Text + "/" + project_number.Text);

        string sourceFile = sourcePath + "/" + "*.*";
        string destinationFile = targetPath + "/" + "*.*";

        System.IO.File.Move(sourceFile, destinationFile);

        System.IO.Directory.Move(sourcePath, targetPath);

    }
```

pathToQuotes and pathToClient are retreived from a MySQL database (from user input) in another method. The info is getting retreived without any problems and the paths are correct. If you could give me a hand it would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a recursive method to achieve moving directories including all files and sub-directories:

```
private void moveDirectory(string sourcePath ,string targetPath)
{
    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath))
    {
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
    }
    String[] files = Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath);
    String[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(sourcePath);
    foreach (string f in files)
    {
        System.IO.File.Copy(f, Path.Combine(targetPath,Path.GetFileName(f)), true);     
    }
    foreach(string d in directories)
    {
        // recursive call
        moveDirectory(Path.Combine(sourcePath, Path.GetFileName(d)), Path.Combine(targetPath, Path.GetFileName(d)));
    }
}
```

then the usage is like this:

```
private void CopyPartsToProject()
{
    string sourcePath = (pathToQuotes + "/" + client_name.Text + "/" + quote_id.Text);
    string targetPath = (pathToClient + "/" + client_name.Text + "/" + project_number.Text);

    moveDirectory(sourcePath, targetPath);
}
```